# ckeditor character count decoding html entities

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, html-entities

```
alert(CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData().replace(/<[^>]*>|\s/g, '').length);
```

I'm using this code to retrieve the character count of text written into the editor.
Unfortunately if writing multiple spaces continuously, it's turns into `&nbsp;`, and when writing some characters such as `á`, it is interpreted as `&aacute;` which is 8 characters long instead of 1.

My question is how could I enhance this line to decode html entities before counting characters.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, I've found an alternative way:

`alert(CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData().replace(/&[^&]*;|\s/g, 'x').replace(/<[^>]*>|\s/g, '').length);`

The htmlentities are turned to 1 character (x).